# How to calculate this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n \cdot H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

> How to calculate this sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n \cdot H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

**Attempt**

The series telescopes. We have
$$=\frac{H_n \cdot H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{H_n \cdot H_{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{H_n \cdot H_{n+1}}{n+2}$$

$$=\frac{H_n(H_n + \frac{1}{n+1})}{n+1} - \frac{(H_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}) \cdot H_{n+1}}{n+2}$$

$$=\frac{H_n^2}{n + 1} - \frac{H_{n+1}^2}{n + 2} + \frac{H_n}{(n + 1)^2}+ \frac{H_{n+1}}{(n + 1)(n + 2)}$$

$$=\frac{H_n^2}{n + 1} - \frac{H_{n+1}^2}{n + 2} + \frac{H_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} + - \frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{H_{n+1}}{n+2}$$

$$=\frac{H_n^2}{n + 1} - \frac{H_{n+1}^2}{n + 2} + \frac{H_{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} + \frac{H_{n + 1}}{n + 1} - \frac{H_{n + 2}}{n + 2} + \frac{1}{{(n + 2)^2}}$$

**It follows that**
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n \cdot H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{H_{n}^2}{n + 1} - \frac{H_{n+1}^2}{(n+2)^2}\right) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}$$

Comment: @Derivative Isn't it $a_n \sim \frac{\log^2 n}{n^2}$?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica gives for the sum: $\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\zeta(3)$.

Comment: @I disagree with Hans Olo. I get $2.607..$ rather than $\zeta(2) + \zeta(3) = 2.84699..$

Comment: So is this going into subcomputations and subquestions or ? Or do you want a different method ?

Comment: @mick Yes, I want to know how to progress further and I’m open to different methods.

Comment: @HansOlo I am sorry, you are correct , I used alpha and he did not spend enough time to get the correct value... +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We use the following summation by parts formula (twice):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}(b_{n+1}-b_n) = -a_1 b_1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n+1}-a_n)b_n \tag1\label1$$
First take $a_n=H_{n-1}H_n$ and $b_n=-1/(n+1)$ in \eqref{1} to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n H_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right) \\
&= \frac{-H_0 H_1}{-(n+1)} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty (H_n H_{n+1}-H_{n-1}H_n)\frac{-1}{n+1} \\
&= 0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n (H_{n+1}-H_{n-1})}{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{(n+1)^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n(n+1)} \\
&= \zeta(3) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right).
\end{align}
Now take $a_n=H_{n-1}$ and $b_n=-1/n$ in \eqref{1} to obtain
$$\zeta(3) + \frac{-H_0}{-1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (H_n-H_{n-1})\frac{1}{n} 
=\zeta(3) + 0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \zeta(3) + \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Comment: Weird. Mathematica gave a different answer. Let me try again ...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+harmonic%28n%29harmonic%28n%2B1%29%2F%28%28n%2B1%29%28n%2B2%29%29

This gives the smaller 2.607 ?

Comment: maybe due to a timeout error ?

Comment: I tried Mathematica and got the same: $\zeta(3) + \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: @mick Watch what happens when you click the "More digits" button.

Comment: @RobPratt lol then I get $2.7$ :) Ok So I guess wolfram did numerical and timeout error :)

Comment: @mick Click it again. :)

Comment: @RobPratt It seems if I click it infinitely often, I will get the right answer :)

Comment: You missed a derivative sign… (+1)

Comment: @Ihateovermoderation "derivative sign"? RobPratt didn't use derivatives at all...

Comment: @jjagmath I think OP meant a missing *minus* sign that I just fixed.

Comment: @jjagmath That is a compliment used by my professor,that sounds good to me so… :)

Answer (score 5):

Multiply both sides of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n+1}x^{n+1}=\frac12\ln^2(1-x)\tag{1}$$ by $-\ln(1-x)$ then integrate from $0$ to $1$ using $-\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln(1-x)dx=\frac{H_{n+2}}{n+2}$, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n} \cdot H_{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}=-\frac12\int_0^1\ln^3(1-x)dx=3\tag{2}$$

Now multiply $(1)$ by $-\ln(x)$ then integrate using $-\int_0^1 x^{n+1}\ln(x)dx=\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}$, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(n+1)(n+2)^2}=-\frac12\int_0^1 \ln(x)\ln^2(1-x)dx=3-\zeta(2)-\zeta(3)\tag{3}$$

Take the difference of $(2)$ and $(3)$, we find

$$\zeta(2)+\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left(H_{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n} \cdot H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Comment: Really impressive!!… (+1)

Comment: (+1) Nice job, Ali! :-)